# Can't save transcribe to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a data for dictionary.

But when system save transcribe to DB, it loses some of the special character.

Ex:

```
group /ɡruːp/
```

When it saves it in DB, it just retains `group /ɡrup/`

It loses `:` character.

What character set can save this value?

I tried with `UTF8`,`UTF8-MB4`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("UTF-16LE");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO words (WORD,WORD_UPPER_CASE, TRANSCRIBE, DESCRIPTION)VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_WORD,$_WORD_UPPER_CASE, $_TRANSCRIBE, $_DESCRIPTION);

// set parameters and execute
$_WORD = $WORD;
$_WORD_UPPER_CASE = $WORD_UPPER_CASE;
$_TRANSCRIBE = $TRANSCRIBE;
$_DESCRIPTION = $DESCRIPTION;

$stmt->execute();   
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: thats only the description, you'll need to provide the code that does the insertion

Comment: What encoding is the input data in? `UTF-16LE`...?! That's rather unusual...

Comment: You don't check whether `->set_charset()` succeeds; I don't think it does. In fact, you don't check for errors anywhere except in connection; that's not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that declaring the encoding cannot go wrong:

```
$conn->set_charset("UTF-16LE");
```

If you run `var_dump($conn->set_charset("UTF-16LE"))` you'll see `bool(false)` because that's not a valid encoding name in MySQL.

In the [See Also](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php#refsect1-mysqli.set-charset-seealso) section of the function documentation you can find a [List of character sets that MySQL supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/charset-charsets.html) link. In my system, UTF encodings include these:

```
mysql> SHOW CHARACTER SET LIKE '%utf%';
+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description    | Default collation  | Maxlen |
+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode  | utf8_general_ci    |      3 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode  | utf8mb4_general_ci |      4 |
| utf16   | UTF-16 Unicode | utf16_general_ci   |      4 |
| utf32   | UTF-32 Unicode | utf32_general_ci   |      4 |
+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Last but not least, you shouldn't be trying out random encodings. Your application charset is something that **you** decide. In 2016 there're little reasons to not use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
So I try to setting utf8mb4  in DB and in PHP code set charset is utf8mb4
but still error

Comment: Please check [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Apart from telling the system that you are using UTF-8, you need to actually use it.